Accuracy and test_accuracy gives a result =1
I've developed a code for classifying hyperspectral images using three different convolutional neural network (CNN) architectures: 1D, 2D, and 3D. The code has two main parts:
Preprocessing and data preparation, which involves tasks such as data splitting (with options for oversampling, PCA, data augmentation, and patch creation). This part concludes by saving the processed data into separate files.
Training and testing the CNN models. However, when evaluating the models, I consistently get accuracy and test accuracy scores of 1, which seems unrealistic. I've attempted to adjust the code, but the results remain unchanged.
I suspect there might be an issue with the code or the data preprocessing steps, but I'm unsure how to troubleshoot further. Any guidance on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated."

Could you elaborate on the nature of this task? My lay impression is that you supply a hyperspectral image (patch) to the net, and it outputs a segmentation labelling individual pixels as land/water/etc?
If so, how is accuracy being measured - do you score it on the number of correct pixels, or on a more general measure like 'this patch is land'?
If you're using a pixel-for-pixel scoring metric, I think it's unlikely a net would score perfectly on unseen data, so there might be a data leakage issue there.
If, instead, you are using a more general patch classification metric where the patches are simply classed as "land" or "water", then it's harder to say what the problem could be. Possibilities that come to mind are:

This particular dataset is easy to classify using hyperspectral images. Perhaps each class has a clear signature in feature space that sets it apart from others. You could try viewing a sample of data going into the net for each class - does each class often look very easy to tell apart? A net could pick up obvious clues.
The validation dataset is small, and by chance the net is scoring perfectly. Shuffling the data or using a larger val set makes this less likely.
The validation set comprises mostly easy cases, in which case you could use stratified sampling to ensure that hard cases are represented as well.
The net might score around 0.95, but it's being rounded up to "1". When reporting the accuracy, you could try printing out the number of samples that scored correctly rather than just their fraction.

